# Javascript navigation only works on debug

Tags: javascript

I have a button which calls a Javascript function when it is pressed, that function is just redirecting to another page, it looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button1" name="button1" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

And the function looks like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    window.location.href = "page2.html";
}
```

The function is executed but the redirection does not work, it remains on the same page, but if I set a breakpoint on the function and execute it line by line using the Browser dev tools it successfully redirects to the other page.

---------EDIT---------

It works only using the Firefox dev tools, if I set the breakpoint on Chrome it still does not works.

Comment: Is your submit button within a form and submitting the form instead?

Comment: Are you seeing an error?

Comment: Can't repro with the information you provided (can't share a jsfiddle, because I don't seem to be able to save).

Comment: Try to use absolute path while navigating a different page.

Comment: The button is inside a form: <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/myProject/page1.html" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="form">

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the href to just

```
location.href = "page2.html".
```

As IE and Firefox are concerned, "/path" is invalid.

"Sorry, cannot leave comment yet"

Comment: I tried that, same behavior, still that does not explain why it works only in debug

Comment: Do you have any other handlers that listen to click on the input or submit on the form ?

Comment: Here is a stripped down version https://gist.github.com/pirvudoru/803eea81d3a2863e6ac2

Answer (score 0):

It's the nature of your input type. Change the type to "button" and you'll be good to go!

Comment: That alone is not the issue. The redirect works perfectly fine with a submit button.

Comment: But the question remains, why it works fine on debug when a breakpoint is set on the function